# Rails ActiveAdmin - edit all new actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I need to override all the `new` actions of several models in AA. Currently I am overriding the models one by one, so I have a lot of duplicated code.

How can I edit all the new actions in one shot?

Just to give some background, I'm doing this in each AA resource file:

```
controller do
  def new
    # things
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create a module and write your methods in that module, then include the module in every controller

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  include YourControllerConcern
  # rest of the controller codes
end
```

but read the [full original answer which I am quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33662740/rails4-methods-shared-by-multiple-controllers), that has additional info

while if you never used `include` this is a [good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318144/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-require-in-ruby#318170) of what it does and this is a complete guide about [`include` and `extend`](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/)